# running hbase shell command through shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts

i am trying to fetch the data value for a key in hbase shell.
i am passing key value in command line argument for which it calculating md5sum in shell script and should scan in hbase.

following is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "cookieId: $1"
md5_hash="$(echo -n "$1"| md5sum | awk '{print $1}')"
echo "$md5_hash"
echo "get 'VIZVR_profile','md5_hash'" | "hbase shell"
```

command which i am running :

```
sh hbase.sh "abcd"
```

but it is throwing error as :

```
hbase.sh: line 5: hbase: command not found
hbase.sh: line 5: : command not found
```

can anybody help me to run this hbase shell command through shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating the 5th line in your script to the below line should solve the problem:

```
echo "get 'VIZVR_profile','md5_hash'" | hbase shell
```

**Explain**

When you execute the following command:

```
echo "get 'VIZVR_profile','md5_hash'" | "hbase shell"
```

The `echo` command is piped into the following command `"hbase shell"`

The problem here, is that there is no command named `"hbase shell"`

The command is `hbase` with parameter `shell`

Removing the quote should solve the problem (assuming that `hbase` is in your `path`).

Note: You might need to replace `hbase` in the 5th line the script with `full/path/to/hbase`